# Присвоить/удалить класс у элемента списка, если в соседнем списке у соответствующего элемента есть/нет класс

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть два списка. При клике по одному из элементов в одном списке ему присваивается класс, а у других удаляется.

**Как сделать**, чтобы в соседнем списке, у соответствующего элемента тоже прикреплялся и удалялся этот класс. То есть, если в первом списке у (третьего например) элемента есть класс `.active`, то и и в другом у этого же элемента он появлялся. желательно чтобы проверка шла в обе стороны.

Ниже написал пример небольшого кода, только пока не понял как связать...

```js
$(".sliderone li").click(function() {
  $(".sliderone li").removeClass("active");         
  $(this).addClass("active");
  if($(".sliderone li:eq("+el+")").hasClass('active')){
  $(".muther .child:eq("+el+")").addClass('active')
  }
})
```

```css
li.active,
.child.active {
  background: #95FFCC;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #2C9A00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sliderone">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="active">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<div class="nextclock">
  <div class="muther">
    <div class="child">11</div>
    <div class="child">22</div>
    <div class="child">33</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, что у одного из элементов этот класс уже стоит, то есть проверка наличия класса должна срабатывать не по клику, а сразу, независимо от того, кликнули или нет.
Не ругайте за ошибки, просто пробую не знаю пока, как.

Comment: а почему бы не использовать сразу какой-нибудь компонент типа tab? :-)

Comment: не понял о чем вы. Знаю только что есть html код с двумя независимыми списками, которые я хочу связать

Comment: выглядит как таб, когда есть список, по клику элементов которого показываются соответствующий контент

Comment: мне не нужен какой-либо контент или таб, просто есть два блока в одном список элементов, а  в другом связанные с каждым элементом блоки. Эти два основных блока выводятся в разных частях странички (вообще в разных) Один в шапке другой где-то внизу справа. Нужно, чтобы когда у одного из элементов сверху есть класс active, то и в блоке снизу у соответствующего элемента этот класс был, чтобы они например подсвечивались одинаково, чтобы было видно что этот блок относится к этому элементу списка а этот к этому.

Comment: Ага :-) вот именно табы и описали :-) можно еще это navbar назвать :-)  вот например уже готовое http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Comment: если бы мне нужен был таб или гармошка какая нибудь то я это бы и искал, но задачу поставил себе четкую: связать элементы из разных списков. пусть этих списков даже 50, главное чтобы соответствующие элементы выделялись классом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36394/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если соответствие по порядковому номеру, то можно использовать функцию [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
$(".sliderone li").click(function() {
  $(".sliderone .active,.muther .active").removeClass("active");
  $(".muther .child:eq(" + $(this).addClass("active").index() + ")").addClass('active')
});

$(".muther .child:eq(" + $(".sliderone .active").index() + ")").addClass('active')
```

```css
li.active,
.child.active {
  background: #95FFCC;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #2C9A00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sliderone">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="active">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<div class="nextclock">
  <div class="muther">
    <div class="child">11</div>
    <div class="child">22</div>
    <div class="child">33</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вот посмотрите, сформулировал вопрос, не знаю насколько близок к решению, но почему-то при клике по третьему элементу все работает http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498684/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83

Comment: ваш ответ тоже важен будет но реализую на другой странице. а вот как реализовать проверку класса, как только он изменится в первом списке - непонятно

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, я честно говоря не понимаю чем отличаются эти вопросы

Comment: не знаю как чат с вами снова открыть объяснению этот момент, почему думал что заработает

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, заходите в него по ссылке под вопросом