# Присвоить/удалить класс у одного из блоков, если в соседнем списке у соответствующего элемента появляется или удаляется класс

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребята внимательно прочитайте суть вопроса. Есть два блока, в одном из них есть маркированный список, в другом обычные блоки, их количество равно друг другу.

Первый маркированный список - это у меня слайдер (то есть переключение класса у элементов маркированного списка происходит по времени), просто вручную я его написать не смог. Но вывел оригинальные теги и классы, а переключение класса реализовал просто по клику.

**Так вот сам вопрос:** как написать функцию, которая бы проверяла, есть ли нужный класс у соответствующего элемента из первого блока, и если есть, то присваивала бы класс, соответствующему элементу во втором блоке. и все это происходило бы динамически, то есть если класс в первом списке перешел к другому элементу то и во втором он бы к следующему (предыдущему) перешел.

у меня класс в первом списке меняется по клику, **НО** переключение класса у элементов во втором блоке должно происходить не по клику, а именно по смене класса у элементов в первом списке независимо от того бы клик или класс изменился сам через определенный интервал.

```js
$("ul.slides li").click(function() {
  $("ul.slides li").removeClass("flex-active-slide");
  $(this).addClass("flex-active-slide");

})

var i = $('ul.slides li.flex-active-slide').index();
setInterval(
  function slide() {
    if ($("ul.slides li:eq(" + i + ")").hasClass("flex-active-slide")) {
      $(".view-desc .views-row:eq(" + i + ")").addClass('active');
    } else {
      $(".view-desc .views-row:eq(" + i + ")").removeClass('active');
    };
  }, 100);
```

```css
 li.flex-active-slide,
 .views-row.active {
   background: #95FFCC;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 2px solid #2C9A00;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
это три элемента слайдера класс у них переключает скрипт:
<ul class="slides">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
-----
<br>а это блоки, и если у элемента списка есть класс "flex-active-slide", то соответствующему блоку тоже тоже должен присвоиться класс "active" но это должна быть независимая от клика функция, то есть она должна срабатывать когда в первом списке сменился
класс
<div class="nextclock">
  <div class="view-desc">
    <div class="views-row">11</div>
    <div class="views-row">22</div>
    <div class="views-row">33</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

почему то только при клике по последнему элементу срабатывает...